# Upload files to salesforce

Tags: sharepoint, salesforce

All

Just wrapping my head around using salesfoce and a use case that I need help on.

So, currently we have SF that is accessible to customer where customer can visualize their documentations like contract, invoice etc.
The relevant team from my department gives me some files and I upload them under the relevant Account--> Documentation section.
However, as you may have witnessed that there is a monotonous work of me manually uploading the documents while being very conscious to upload the right document under the right Account.

So, my SF friends please help me if there is an automated solution available that can take files from a specific Sharepoint location and upload it under a relevant account. I would like to maintain a monthly folder for the customer so that they know what document to look for in which month.

I am open to some other suggestion as well on how to send file, however the input are files like PDF/ CSV's / WOrd Doc etc.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds quite tedious. Have you looked into any SharePoint/Salesforce connectors? I can recall Files Connect offhand, not sure if meets your needs.

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to:

1. Enable the REST API in SharePoint
2. Use POSTMAN to download a single document.
3. Call that a milestone.

Then next step is decide on what you want to happen in Salesforce.
Either:

a. Create a page in Salesforce - and build out classes to execute GET/POST commands and render the document.

OR:

a. Extract all documents from SharePoint
b. Use DataLoader upload the documents into Salesforce CRM.

Salesforce CRM allows you to:

1. Associate your uploaded document to any Salesforce Id via the field: contentversion.FirstPublishLocationId
2. Dataloader will know where to find the document to upload via the field: contentversion.PathOnClient

We're supposed to avoid answers like this one. So click if this answer is helpful.